# No space left on device, with 320 GB free

Tags: filesystems, windows, disk-usage

I'm a bit lost. I have a 500 GB external hard drive with its original filesystem still in place. The last command (`dd` writing to a file within this filesystem) failed with "no space left on device".

Still, I think there is plenty of space:

```
root# pwd
/media/john/HD-CEU2

root# df -h .
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1       466G  335G  132G  72% /media/john/HD-CEU2

root# df -i .
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1        132M   23K  132M    1% /media/john/HD-CEU2

root# du -hs .
335G    .

root# mount | grep `pwd`
/dev/sdb1 on /media/john/HD-CEU2 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096
```

This is an external harddrive with the original filesystem. Looks like some windows stuff, or why else would Ubuntu mount it as "fuseblk".

```
lsof | grep `pwd`
(Nothing except for 2 shells having a handle on the root directory /media/john/HD-CEU2)
```

It would seem that the disk has still 132 GB available. But the `dd` command wrote a file of 280 GB (300158177280 bytes) and then failed with "No space left on device". I *can* create new files sized about 100 MB without any error.

**Is this caused by some limitation of the (windows) file system?**

**How can I even identify the file system?** (`file -s /dev/sdb1` returns "x86 boot sector", `fdisk -l dev/sdb` returns `7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT`. Is it NTFS?)

UPDATE: I can't *prove* that there was enough space when the `dd` failed, but I can't imagine any process in the background taking more than 130 GB.

Comment: You're trying to write a 280 GB file into 132 GB and you're actually surprised that you get a "no space left" message?

Comment: @John, the "no space left" came first, the 280 GB target file is there, and now I'm surprised to still see 132 GB left.

Comment: Try writing small files in a loop till the disk is more or less full?

Comment: You could try identifying the file system using `mount`.

Comment: Please show your `dd` command and the size of the file you're copying.

Comment: related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222221/how-to-fix-intermittant-no-space-left-on-device-errors-during-mv-when-device-h