# "No space left on device" depending on alphanumeric filename, adding or removing a character works

Tags: directory, ext4

I just encountered this most curious of errors:

```
$ touch 3a59199733b83a8dba88b48c3f3c6fac05699ea8f1dd5ef7540ee57d64896d6d
touch: cannot touch '3a59199733b83a8dba88b48c3f3c6fac05699ea8f1dd5ef7540ee57d64896d6d': No space left on device
```

But

```
$ touch 3a59199733b83a8dba88b48c3f3c6fac05699ea8f1dd5ef7540ee57d64896d6
```

and

```
$ touch 3a59199733b83a8dba88b48c3f3c6fac05699ea8f1dd5ef7540ee57d64896d6d1
```

both work (i.e removing last char or adding a 1 at the end). I don't have exact statistics, but given thousands of file creations (all with similar names, i.e. their hashes), only a handful fail (<100 out of >10000 if I read the logs right).

The disk is not full:

```
$ df -h .
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb2        17T  7.6T  8.0T  49% /mnt/deb67853-226b-4939-9bd1-3167199a8160
```

and does have free inodes:

```
$ df -i .
Filesystem        Inodes   IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sdb2      274667520 9635078 265032442    4% /mnt/deb67853-226b-4939-9bd1-3167199a8160
```

The folder is larger than sensible:

```
$ find . -type f | wc -l
5545647
$ du -hs .
937G    .
```

but nothing crazy. It's flat, with a bit more than 5 million files named like their hashes totalling slightly less than 1TB.

The file system seems healthy:

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdb2       
tune2fs 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /mnt/deb67853-226b-4939-9bd1-3167199a8160                                                                                   
Filesystem UUID:          deb67853-226b-4939-9bd1-3167199a8160
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              274667520
Block count:              4394674432
Reserved block count:     219733721
Overhead clusters:        17749519
Free blocks:              2513260923
Free inodes:              268217713
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Group descriptor size:    64
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         2048
Inode blocks per group:   128
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Sat Nov 11 18:40:27 2023
Last mount time:          Tue Jan  2 23:10:53 2024
Last write time:          Tue Jan  2 23:10:53 2024
Mount count:              24
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Sat Nov 11 18:40:27 2023
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          10 TB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:               256
Required extra isize:     32
Desired extra isize:      32
Journal inode:            8
First orphan inode:       60129282
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      a2cba75e-f220-4e34-9e6a-af4d7f404e57
Journal backup:           inode blocks
Checksum type:            crc32c
Checksum:                 0x34552f53
```

My pragmatic solution right now was to rename the folder and create a new empty one in its stead, this seems to have fixed it. I could "add slashes" to the filenames to avoid having folders with too many files (which I assume is the root cause in some indirect way), but I would prefer to avoid this right now.

Comment: Oh, in the related question there is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222221/how-to-fix-intermittant-no-space-left-on-device-errors-during-mv-when-device-h?rq=1 which I somehow didn't see before asking. Probably dir_index is the problem.